# Parsing huge json array in Swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I am new to `Swift` and I wanted to know how to parse huge Json array in Swift. I am familiar with `Jackson` and `GSON` but these libraries only work for Java. Is there some kind of fast way to parse huge json array in `Swift`. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the Github repo SwiftyJSON. I use it for parsing all JSON data! https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

The documentation is really good and teaches you everything you need to know to use it.

Hope this helps!